# cordova inappbrowser blank white screen

Tags: cordova-plugins, payment-gateway, inappbrowser

I'm not able to load this url in the inappbrowser https://certepayments.omannet.cbo.gov.om/. 
loadstartCallback and loadstopCallback are working but a blank white screen is appearing when I call this url, 
If this gets loaded then I hope I can move forward with inappbrowser _blank option for integrating payment gateway.

On changing to target =_blank to _self, this works, but a black screen is appearing for 5 seconds which is not acceptable from a user perspective.

```
var target = '_blank';
var options = "location=yes";
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://certepayments.omannet.cbo.gov.om/", target, options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadloaderror', loaderrorCallback);
ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);

function loadstartCallback(event) {
  console.log('Loading started: '  + event.url)
}

function loadstopCallback(event) {
  console.log('Loading finished: ' + event.url)
}

function loaderrorCallback(error) {
  console.log('Loading error: ' + error.message)
}

function exitCallback() {
  console.log('Browser is closed...')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because certificate being used by above specified payment URL is either self signed or not secure.There are two options to resolve this issue-
1) purchase licenced certificate from.valid certificate authority.
2) Ignore SSL check from code(Not recommended for production environment)